# Shared volume during build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose environment setup like so:

Oracle
Filesystem
App
... 
etc...

The filesystem container downloads the latest code from our repo and exposes its volume for other containers to mount. This works great except that containers that need to use the code to do builds can't access it since the volume isn't mounted until the containers are run.

I'd like to avoid checkout/downloading the code since the codebase is over 3 gig right now... Hence trying to do something spiffier.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Docker volumes won't work as volumes are used when the container start.

The best solution for your situation is to use [Docker multistage Builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). The idea here is to have an image which has the code base and other images can access this code directly from this image.

You basically have an image, that is responsible for pulling the code:

```
FROM alpine/git
RUN git clone ...
```

You then build this image, either separately or as the first image in a compose file.

Other images can then use this image as such:

```
FROM code-image as code

COPY --from=code /git/<code-repository> /code
```

This will make the code available to all the images, and it will only be pulled once from the remote repo.